# getAttribute of a element in ksoap2 , android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

So , i have a soap service , from which i get some response like the following :

```
<xml>   
  <SpinnerMaster name="masterStatus">
              <value>Unknown</value>
              <value>Not Started</value>
              <value>Excavation</value>
              <value>Piling</value>
              <value>Plinth</value>
              <value>Floor Slab</value>
              <value>Internal Work</value>
              <value>External Work</value>
              <value>Complete</value>
            </SpinnerMaster>


<status type="drop" editable="1">1</status>
</xml>
```

So when i want to access the attribute of the SpinnerMaster it is simple :

```
((SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("SpinnerMaster")).getAttribute("name")
```

but when I try to do the same with the status element I face with the class cast exception .

```
((SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("status")).getAttribute("type")
```

Well , the exception is pretty straight forward - soapObject.getProperty("status") returns a string and then i cannot cast it back to SoapObject but then in this situation how can I get the attribute type of element status .